# How to get members of class in LLDB through pointer to class instance

Tags: c++, lldb

I am now using LLDB (pretty new user) in MAC. I have the following sample code:

```
 MessageCacheItem::pointer msg = getValue(objId);
 bool outdated = (NULL != msg.get()) && (msgSentTime > msg->m_msgSentTime);
 return outdated;
```

`MessageCacheItem` is a class that has a private member `m_msgSentTime`. Inside LLDB, I used the following command:

```
fr v msg->m_msgSentTime
```

It gave me the following error:

> error: "msg" is not a pointer and -> was used to attempt to access "m_msgSentTime". Did you mean "badge.m_msgSentTime"?

While `msg` is a shared_pointer to the class instance.

My question is: **How do I examine members of class with pointer to class instance in LLDB**?

Comment: have you tried `msg.get()->m_msgSentTime` - I have a feeling `lldb` and other debuggers don't typically understand `operator->` and similar constructs.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I tried, it does not work.

Comment: @MatsPetersson That's very sad if we don't have an IDE to debug it and the code is built with clang++

Comment: Well, I have certainly debugged llvm-based code by doing `ptr->somefunction()->somestuff`. Exactly what is the error message you get when you use`msg.get()`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I just tried again, here is the error message: error: "get()" is not a member of "(MessageCacheItem::pointer) msg"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
fr v msg->m_msgSentTime
```

use the following instead:

```
p msg->msgSentTime
```

However, I have not found where is the difference between these two commands yet (Just in case someone might see the same issue, I answered my own question). If any LLDB guru knows the difference, you are welcomed to add more.

Comment: p is a shortcut for "expression". When you say "p <something>", you are acting as if that code was part of your source program, invoking clang to compile it and execute it on your behalf. In some simple cases, LLDB will actually interpret the LLVM IR instead of JITting stuff in your inferior process and executing, but you get the point.

Comment: frame variable does not involve evaluating code, nor clang. It knows to show local variables, and it has a very simple parser for syntaxes of the form a.b, a->b and a few more, but it will not evaluate an expression, and rely solely on LLDB's understanding of your types, to construct the resulting value.

Comment: For instance, you are very welcome to do p myClassPtr->iVar + 3, but the same won't work with frame variable. Also, p myClass.someMethod(45,a) is a valid expression, but won't work with frame variable. On the other hand, a plain frame variable command will show all your local variables and arguments, that which you can't do in one shot with the expression command.

Answer (score 1):

`frame variable` (`fr v`) has *very* simple C language syntax knowledge built in to it.  It works on variables local to a stack frame (or global variables if you use `target variable`) - it knows how to dereference a pointer (`*`, `->`) and it knows how to look at a sub element of a structure (`.`) and I think it can do array indexing (`[1]`).  But that's about it.  You definitely can't do a function call like `fr v msg.get()->m_msgSentTime` (or `fr v msg->m_msgSentTime` which is equivalent).  You can't put any type casts in your variable expression with `frame variable`.

You might have been able to do this with something like `fr v msg.__ptr_->m_msgSentTime` or whatever, depending on the implementation of your shared pointer object.